# Constrained summation problem

Tags: equation-solving

Here is a problem from *Brilliant.org*:

[image]

where each symbol has a fixed numerical value and the sums in each row and column are given (except one).  The task is to find the sum in the first row.

Why doesn't this code give the answer directly?

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, x];
Solve[a + b + c == x &&
  a + b + d == 19 &&
  c + c + d == 14 &&
  a + a + c == 15 &&
  b + b + d == 13 &&
  c + d + d == 19, x]
```

even after restricting to `Integers`?

Comment: `b + b + d` should be `b + b + c`. And then changing `x` to `{a, b, c, d, x}` in the `Solve` gives `{{a -> 6, b -> 5, c -> 3, d -> 8, x -> 14}}`.

Answer (score 4):

Using the graphics is nice, but it is also possible to just use glyphs in `Solve[]` as an alternative:

```
mat = {{●, ■, ★}, {●, ■, ▲}, {★, ★, ▲}};

Solve[Total[mat] == {15, 13, 19} && Total[mat, {2}] == {x, 19, 14}, x, Union[Flatten[mat]]]
   {{x -> 14}}
```

Note the use of the (now) *undocumented* form of `Solve[]` where one specifies variables to be eliminated. If one is not comfortable with this,

```
Eliminate[Join[Thread[Total[mat] == {15, 13, 19}], Thread[Total[mat, {2}] == {x, 19, 14}]],
          Union[Flatten[mat]]]
   x == 14
```

also directly yields an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Of course (?), you might have spotted your mistake immediately if you had simply solved for the original graphics ...

[image]

and I guess that with a bit more effort I (or someone smarter) might turn the input into a copy of the original grid of graphics.

Comment: Hah!  I never thought of using the *graphics*... very cool.